# Convert SharePoint 2010 templates to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, site-template

Is it possible to convert a Sharepoint 2010 wsp file (created by using the "save site as template" command) to a version that works with Sharepoint Online?

I don't have access to Visual Studio.

The error message that I see when uploading and activating is:

> This site template doesn't work with the current version of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

No. It might technically be possible but certainly not feasible. You'll have to create it all over again from scratch, or embrace the future and move to an automated provisioning approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to convert the WSP solution to SharePoint [Add-In mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins) because 
farm solutions and sandbox solutions with custom code aren't supported in SharePoint Online . You must re-write your application as SharePoint Add-in (SharePoint-hosted or Provider-hosted). Read [Transform farm solutions to the SharePoint add-in model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/transform-farm-solutions-to-the-sharepoint-app-model) .